# How I can do a "Join" in for the matched data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my query, I want to filter my result by the employee number in this case "1311" but it shows all the employees

```
db.Trabajador.aggregate([ 
 { $lookup: { 
  "localField": "idTrabajador", 
  "from": "Asignacion",
  "foreignField": "idTrabajador",
  "as": "Trabajadores" } }
],{"$Asignacion.idTrabajador":"1311"}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this, using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/):

```
db.Trabajador.aggregate([
 { "$match": { "idTrabajador": "1311" } },
 { "$lookup": { 
  "localField": "idTrabajador", 
  "from": "Asignacion",
  "foreignField": "idTrabajador",
  "as": "Trabajadores"
 }}
]).pretty()
```

Which basically finds the matching employee only and then does the "join" to the related data in the other collection.

Comment: Sorry it worked now, only I removed the "" of the employee number, thanks dude!